# SBT protobuf grpc configuration

Tags: sbt, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm new to SBT, and i'm trying to convert gradle protobuf/grpc configuration to SBT.

I wonder if the Scala community had done this before me?

I've tried this plugin https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf, but it does not provide any configuration to enable grpc compilation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually faced a couple of problems myself trying to migrate from Gradle to SBT.

Like you said, `sbt-protobuf` plugin doesn't have any `grpc` specific settings, yet it's possible, here are couple of settings you should double check:

- Set the *path* and *version* of your `protoc`:

  `version in PB.protobufConfig := "3.0.0"
  protoc in PB.protobufConfig := PATH_PROTOC`
- If needed set the location of your `.proto` files (default is `src/main/protobuf`):

  `sourceDirectory in PB.protobufConfig := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "proto"`
- Finally, like [Eric Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690866/eric-anderson) said, set extra options of `protoc` used by `grpc-java`. First options sets the path for your `protoc-gen-grpc-java` plugin bin; and second sets the output path of grpc-java to the same as `sbt-protobuf`:

  `protocOptions in PB.protobufConfig ++= Seq(
      "--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=" + PATH_GRPC_JAVA_PLUGIN,
      "--grpc-java_out=" + baseDirectory.value +    "/target/src_managed/main/compiled_protobuf")`

I ended up putting a repository with all of this sorted out. [Here it is](https://github.com/jfloff/grpc-java-sbt), hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for sharing, i've simply isolated protobuf generation to a separate gralde mini project. Honestly sbt is piece of crap, i'll avoid using it at all costs... sadly we have play framework around..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ScalaPB](https://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/) to generate the gRPC stubs for Scala. First, add the plugin to your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.1")
libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.5.43"
```

Then, add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.0.1",
  "io.grpc" % "grpc-stub" % "1.0.1",
  "io.grpc" % "grpc-auth" % "1.0.1",
  "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % "0.5.43",
  "io.netty" % "netty-tcnative-boringssl-static" % "1.1.33.Fork19",  // SSL support
  "javassist" % "javassist" % "3.12.1.GA"  // Improves Netty performance
)

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen(grpc = true, flatPackage = true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)
```

Now you can put your .proto files in `src/main/protobuf` and they will be picked up by ScalaPB.

I have an [example Scala gRPC project here](https://github.com/vyshane/grpc-scala-microservice-kit). It shows how to configure mutual TLS authentication, user sessions using JSON Web Tokens, a JSON gateway via [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway), and deployment to Kubernetes via [Helm](https://helm.sh).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sbt, but it seems sbt-protobuf does not natively support protoc plugins or using the prebuilt [protoc](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.protobuf%22%20a%3A%22protoc%22) or [protoc-gen-grpc-java](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.grpc%22%20a%3A%22protoc-gen-grpc-java%22) binaries. You will need to pass the [necessary flags](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v0.13.2/compiler/README.md#compiling-and-testing-the-codegen) manually.

Something like this (untested):

```
protocOptions in PB.protobufConfig ++= Seq(
    "--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=path/to/protoc-gen-grpc-java", "--grpc-java_out=path/to/output/folder")
```

You would need to change the "path/to" parts to fit your system.